# Windows Server VPN: Error 720

Tags: windows, vpn, pptp

I want to created vpn server on Windows Server 2012.
First I installed Active Directory domain services, then Remote Access server role. Opened Gettng Started Wizard, entered configure just vpn. Then in Routing and Remote access selected Configure and Enable Routing and Remote Access. There selected custom configuration, vpn. Then created user in active directory and allowed network access permission. After this I tried to connect to vpn from windows 8. I get the following error:
Error 720: A connection t the remote computer could not be established. You might need to change the network settings for this connection.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

[Consult the list of Windows VPN error codes here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824864).

> 720
>
> No PPP control protocols configured.

Based on the Microsoft support KBs, there seem to be three primary causes.

1. ["This behavior can occur if your computer and the RAS server do not have a protocol in common, or if RAS is not configured correctly."](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314869)
2. ["This can occur if TCP/IP is damaged or is not bound to your dial-up adapter."](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312840)
3. ["If the RAS component (of RRAS) is configured to use DHCP to assign remote TCP/IP client addresses and there is no DHCP server reachable, RRAS is not able to set up a dial-up connection and will return the above error message. "](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/217126)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows Server 2012 box with RRAS in front of me right now so I can't get you exact screenshots or naming, but you do need to configure Connection Policies and Network Policies that define who is allowed to connect and what they can connect to.  It is usually part of the Network Policy Server tool for configuration of these policies.